# behat mink symfony2 Warning

Tags: php, symfony, behat, mink

I try to make functional tests with the bundle Behat and Mink

However, after having installed the Bundle and all, I issued the command

```
php app / console test-e = Behat - init @ AcmeDemoBundle
```

but I get this error:

> PHP Warning: require_once (C: \ wamp \ www \ exoNext-local \ trunk \
>   app /.. / Vendor / doctrin e / lib / Doctrine / ORM / Mapping / Driver
>   / DoctrineAnnotations.php): failed to open strea m: No such file or
>   directory in C: \ wamp \ www \ exoNext-local \ trunk \ vendor \
>   doctrine- common \ lib \ Doctrine \ Common \ Annotations \
>   AnnotationRegistry.php on line 51

could you help me please, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To init a bundle I use

```
$ php app/console --env=test behat --init @AcmeDemoBundle
```

But your error is related to a doctrine annotation?

Comment: i think, i just realized now that even if I try to do a simple test with phpunit I have the same error ... oups !!

Answer (score 0):

```
C: \ wamp \ www \ exoNext-local \ trunk \ app /.. / Vendor / doctrin e / lib / Doctrine / ORM / Mapping / Driver / DoctrineAnnotations.php
```

Shouldn't "Vendor" be "vendor" ? I know windows is case insensitive but require_once can face case sensitivity problems in some cases.

Comment: may be, but I checked the vendor file and the file is ORM exite do not even

I think this is the commende "php bin / vendor install" that caused this problem

I will try to redo everything

Thank you

Comment: Try fixing the path in app/autoload.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these two commands first and then yours:

```
composer dump-autoload
composer run-script post-update-cmd
```

I hope it helps :-)